# RequireJS - $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, requirejs, datatables

I am having a lot of trouble with getting jQuery DataTables to work.  I have been looking in numerous places, and just can't seem to get to the bottom of it.

The error I receive via Chrome developer tools is:

> $(...).DataTable is not a function

**app.js:**

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "../Scripts",
    "paths": {
        app: "./app",
        essentials: "./dist/essentials.min",
        jquery: "./dist/jquery-1.10.2.min",
        "jquery.bootstrap": "./dist/bootstrap.min"
        "jquery.dataTables": "./dist/jquery.dataTables.min",
        "jquery.dataTables.bootstrap": "./dist/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.min"

    },
    "shim": {
        "essentials": ["jquery"],
        "jquery.dataTables": ["jquery"],
        "jquery.dataTables.bootstrap": ["jquery.dataTables"],
        "jquery.bootstrap": ["jquery"]
    }
});

// Load the main app module to start the app
requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

**main.js (not in use):**

```
require(["jquery"], function ($) {
    $(function () {
    });
});
```

**Create.js (Generated from TypeScript):**

```
define(["require", "exports", "../../Shared/ModalHelper"], function (require, exports, Helper) {
    require(["jquery", "essentials", "jquery.bootstrap", "jquery.dataTables", "jquery.dataTables.bootstrap"], function ($) {
        function initilializeTables() {
            var attrSelectDataTable = $('#selectAttrsTable').DataTable({
                paging: true,
                bInfo: true,
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
                ],
                scrollY: 400
            });
            var attrPreviewDataTable = $('#selectedAttrsTable').DataTable({
                paging: true,
                bInfo: true,
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 },
                    { "orderable": false, "targets": 5 }
                ],
                scrollY: 400
            });

        }

        initilializeTables();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since DataTables declares itself as a named module, the "datatables" name has to be used when declaring a name for the path in require config.

Live [example](http://live.datatables.net/deluluk/1/edit) here. Credit to [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20660/solved-datatables-with-requirejs-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the cause of the error is:

- Missing jQuery library (`./dist/jquery-1.10.2.min.js`)

  OR
- Missing jQuery DataTables plug-in (`./dist/jquery.dataTables.min.js`)

  OR
- jQuery DataTables version is 1.9.x or below. First line of `jquery.dataTables.min.js` should contain plug-in version.

  Method `DataTable()` only became available in jQuery DataTables 1.10.